# Posting photo from Cordova to Spring Web Service

Tags: java, android, ajax, spring, cordova

I am writing a proof of concept app that consists of a Sencha Touch/ Cordova hybrid application that accesses an phones camera API, takes an picture and uploads it to a Spring Server. I have got the the mobile application jamming properly. I have managed to take the picture but I am having issues posting it to the Spring back end. When I debug the server I can see that the app is hitting the web service correctly, but the image byte[] seems to be blank. I debugged this on the client side using Android logcat and there image is definitely being sent from the client side. I think that the problem lies with my webservice that is receiving the posted image.

My basic client side code is as follows :

```
  function onPhotoUriSuccess(imageUriToUpload){
    var url=encodeURI("http://192.168.2.4:8080/app/api/rest//uploadImage/");

    var params = new Object();
    params.your_param_name = "something";  //you can send additional info with the file

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "the_name_of_the_image_field"; //depends on the api
    options.fileName = imageUriToUpload.substr(imageUriToUpload.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = true; //this is important to send both data and files

    var headers={'Authorization':'TOKEN_BASED_AUTHENTICATION '+ localStorage.getItem('Token')};
    options.headers = headers;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    console.log("Donovan");
    console.log("image uri" + imageUriToUpload)
    ft.upload(imageUriToUpload, url, win, fail, options, true);

}

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode.toString()+"\n");
    console.log("Response = " + r.response.toString()+"\n");
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent.toString()+"\n");
    alert("Code Slayer!!!");
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
}

Ext.define('PhotoBomb.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.Button',
        'Ext.Img'
    ],
    config: {
        layout: {
            type:"vbox",
            pack:"center",
            align:"center"
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: "image",
                src: "http://placehold.it/200x200",
                width: 200,
                height: 200
            },
            {
                xtype: "button",
                text: "Photo",
                handler: function()
                {
                    console.log('Handler for launching camera');
                    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoUriSuccess, onFail,
                        {
                            quality: 40,
                            destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                            encodingType : navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                            targetWidth: 500,
                            targetHeight: 500,
                            saveToPhotoAlbum: 1
                        });

                    function onFail(){
                        Ext.Msg.alert(message);
                        console.log(message);
                    }

                    function refreshImages()
                    {
                        console.log('Image Gallery refreshed');
                    }

                }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

My basic spring webservice is as follows :

```
Path("/uploadImage/")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("*/*")
public interface ImagePostWebService {
    /**
     * A Web service that handles tokens
     */
        @POST
        String postPicture(InputStream streame);
}
```

And implementation

```
   @Override
    public String postPicture(InputStream image) {
        byte [] images;
        try {
            images = IOUtils.toByteArray(image);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return "Mother Trucker";
        }

        boolean empty = true;
        for (byte b : images) {
            if (b != 0) {
                empty = false;
            }
        }
        if (empty) {
            return "empty";
        }

               log.info("image upload webservice hit");
       log.info(Arrays.toString(images));

        Employee employee = contextBeanService.getLoggedOnEmployee();
        UploadRequestDTO uploadRequest = new UploadRequestDTO(employee.getId(), DocumentType.CLIENT_MUGSHOT,
                "new.jpg", "image/jpeg");
        uploadRequest.setExtension("jpg");
        try {
        documentCRUDMappingService.createDocument(DocumentType.CLIENT_MUGSHOT, uploadRequest, images,
                employee.getId());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {

        }

        return "done";
    }
```

When I run the application and debug the server side it I can see it hitting the webservice, when I print out the byte[] received it is as follows : [115, 111, 109, 101, 116, 104, 105, 110, 103], this isnt what I would expect for an image from an samsung S4mini camera phone, I think I am missing something with regards to uploading the image from cordova to my spring webservice. Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of my problem was that I had made the incorrect assumption that I was using Spring for the webservice, when in fact I was using Java web services. Once I discovered this it was pretty straight forward to sort my problems out. I was in fact missing a form paramater so my webservice was never actually expecting an image. The fix to my web service interface was as follows :

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/uploadImage/")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("*/*")
public interface ImagePostWebService {
    /**
     * A Web service that handles tokens
     */
        @POST
        String postPicture(@FormParam("image") String image);
}
```